# How to deploy Angular Universal project to virtual directory in plesk

Tags: angular, iis, plesk, angular-universal, angular-route-segment

i want deploy angular universal project in my domain virtual directory but issue is that when i deploy project it not load any css js(asssets) and inner pages

e.g domain.com/virtual directory but when open it not load its assets saying not found
domain.com/css altough it has to be this domain.com/Virtual Direcory/css

Answer (score 0):

When you do the build, you can specify the `--deploy-url` option

```
ng build --deploy-url /virtualDirectory
```

This will add the specified prefix to the scripts

Comment: i build using this npm run build:ssr can you help me in this detail

Comment: And what does `npm run build:ssr` do?

Comment: and it can also use for domain.com/page

Comment: Open up you package.json,  find the line that says `build:ssr`, and add the option I indicated above

Comment: npm run build:ssr --deploy-url /virtualDirectory  i used this comand it given me this error
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/virtualDirectory'

Comment: in my package jsoon 
lines are this plz help how to amend

"compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run SampleData:server:production --bundleDependencies all"